# React-Router and Redux won't work together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm having this problem where I can't access my redux function inside a nested component, I think the problem has to do with react-router.

**This is my index.js:**

```
const store = createStore(UserReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**This is my app.js:**

```
class App extends Component {

  static propTypes: {
    user: {
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      token: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
  };

  handleInput = (evt) =>
  this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value} });

  render() {

    const { dispatch, id, token } = this.props;
    const addUser = bindActionCreators(UserActionCreators.addUser, dispatch);

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <Landing/>
              )}/>
              <Route path="/sign_in" render={() => (
                  <LogIn handleInput={this.handleInput} addUser={addUser}/>
                )} />
                <Route path="/sign_up" render={() => (
                    <SignUp/>
                  )} />
                  <Route path="/users" render={({match}) => (
                      <Users user={this.state.user} match={match} {...this.props} />
                    )} />
                  </Switch>
                  <Footer />
                </div>
              </BrowserRouter>
            );
          }
        }
        const mapStateToProps = state => (
          {
            id: state.id,


      token: state.token
      }
    );

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

And I'm trying to pass my addUser function to the Login component but in at the moment where I try to call the function It will tell me that my function is not defined.

Also I have this code at the end of my Log In component, which is a class.

```
LogIn.propTypes = {
    addUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }


  export default withRouter(LogIn);
```

**Here's how my UserActionCreators.addUser looks like:**

```
export const addUser = (id, token) => {
  return{
    type: UserActionTypes.ADD_USER,
    id,
    token
  };
};


export const ADD_USER = 'user/ADD_USER';
```

Comment: You have a typo. It's `dispatch` not `distpatch` in the first 2 lines of your `render` function.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't see the typo. But It still giving me the problem "TypeError: _this.addUser is not a function" when I try to run the function.

Comment: How does `UserActionCreators.addUser` look like?

Comment: I just added the code!

Comment: this.props.addUser

Comment: Where should I put that? @Asool

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      addUser: () => dispatch(userActionCreators.addUser())
    }
}
```

Add this code right after mapStateToProps, and modify your export to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Now you can access addUser via this.props.addUser anywhere in your code.

Comment: Now is giving me the error "TypeError: dispatch is not a function"

Comment: You have mapStateToProps before mapDispatchToProps right, in your connect function? ... And you have redux thunk?

Comment: Yes I have it before, I don't have redux thunk tho, I'll try installing that

Comment: I installed it and created the store like this `const store = createStore(UserReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));` But still not working

Comment: sorry to bother but do you have any idea why isn't it working?